Bone Constraints - Menu is empty (Just a Plus and Minus icon)
I created a very simple Armature, unconnected and unparented. Just 3 floating bones.
For my needs, i have to assign a Bone Constraint to one of them, so i go into Pose Mode, but the menu is empty, except from a greyed out "+" icon and a clear "-" minus. When i click the "-" icon, Blender says "No saved presets".
As for the scene, there's nothing in particular to be noted. The Armature is completly devoid of anything, it's just empty bones.
EDIT - Workaround : For some reason, going into the top menu Pose > Constraints > Add (With targets) (Or CTRL + SHIFT + C) does work, but adds an empty object to the scene. Deleting it and reassigning the Constraint to the correct object seems to do the trick.

I've never seen this before, anyone have an idea of what i'm missing ?
Thank you !
